# Returning a contained result in a hasMany find in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a pretty straightforward Model relationship: a POST hasMany COMMENTs.

They're both correctly related to each other and they both have the Containable attribute turned on.

Is there any way to perform a find on POSTs and return an array of just POST ids and each of its COMMENT ids?

I can easily contain other relationships, but not hasMany. Right now I'm just performing a find at recursive level 0 and grabbing the fields that I need. But this array has so much junk I don't need in it, like USER info and tags. I'd rather trim all of that stuff out and get a neat array returned. Please help.

Also, first post, please forgive me if I did anything wrong.

Comment: You need to include some code (the action where you want to performe this find on POSTs and an example of what you've tried). Explain a bit better what you want to do, and why does it fail.

Comment: are you adding a belongsTo in Comment.php? If you do this all should work just fine!